# Undefined index with Codeigniter CSV Import

Tags: csv, codeigniter, import

I'm trying to import a CSV File with Codeigniter, which contains the code below:

```
Voornaam;Achternaam;email
John;Doe;john.doe@gmail.com
Man;Made;man@made.com
```

The file is successfully uploaded, and when I print the code through PHP it indeed shows me the file contents in an array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Voornaam] => John [Achternaam] => Doe [email] => john.doe@gmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [Voornaam] => Man [Achternaam] => Made [email] => man@made.com ) )
```

The code is then processed through the following code:

```
foreach($csv_array as $row) {
     $insertData = array(
      'firstName' => $row['Voornaam'],
      'lastName' => $row['Achternaam'],
      'email' => $row['email']
    );
};
```

Which unfortunately 'Undefined index: Voornaam' When i replace $row['Voornaam'] with '', the code processes fine, so lastName and email work. Now, I cannot for the life of me figure out why Voornaam is not processed, and how it may be fixed.

Comment: could you show how you create the $csv_array from the csv string/file?

Comment: Certainly, it's too long to add as a comment, it can be found here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/971379f9228b9b03fe5e8327d6ae158320a8225e

Comment: Please follow this example hope so helpful for you : link here https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-import-csv-file-data-into-mysql-database/

Comment: I tested that example before, but it appears to be broken.

Comment: I'm still struggling, anyone able to help?